# get_post_meta not working in different language

Tags: wordpress

I have this code: 
$variable = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_fcs_hp_spsite', true);

I am using Polylang plugin. For Suomi language it works perfect (it returns the post ID). On English language, it doesn't return nothing (even the post is there for sure). It worked before and it just stopped (I think after some irelevant text change in one of the posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I believe there's a "synchronization of custom fields" setting on the plugin settings. Make sure you have that checked.

Comment: It looks that I have made a mistake, those posts actually didn't have the same Id. So the problem is solved. Thank you very much for your effort.